# Should credit for an idea in an SO Q or A be given by a link to the user's page?

Tags: discussion, attribution

Should credit for an idea in an SO question or answer be given by a link to the user's page or is a link to their question or answer enough since it will contain a link to their user page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say link directly to the source of the idea. If the idea stems from a question or answer, link to either the question or the answer. If the idea stems from some verbal discussion you had with the user, link to the user.